# Laravel orchestral/testbench issues with Mockery

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, mockery

Say i have two test cases that need to use a `Foo` object.

In the first test case i need `Foo` to be mocked so i'm doing

```
class TestCaseA extends \Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase {
    function testA() {
        $foo = \Mockery::mock('Foo')->shouldReceive('baz')->once();
        Something::method_That_Uses_A_Dependency_Injected_Foo();
    }
}
```

In the second test case i need the real `Foo` implementation, so i'm doing

```
class TestCaseB extends \Orchestra\Testbench\TestCasez
    function testB() {
      $foo = new Foo();
      $foo->baz();
    }
}
```

When the `TestCaseA` is ran first, `TestCaseB` fails because it's actually using the mocked instance and i get a

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Foo::baz() does not exist on this mock object
```

On the contrary, when `TestCaseB` run first i get an exception from Mockery that's stating something like *"Can't create mock because the real Foo object has been loaded already."* (sorry but i forgot the actual exception).

What i think i need here is a sort of isolation between the test cases  autoloaders, but i've no idea how to achieve this. Any hint?

P.S. i'm not sure that orchestral/testbench is actually involved in this issue, i think it's mostly a Mockery thing.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it right now but aren't you missing a call to close() to stop the mocking?

```
\Mockery::close();
```